# Navier-Stokes - Reynolds decomposition of energy equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, notation, navier-stokes

I am trying to apply the Reynolds decomposition to the Navier-Stokes equations for incompressible flows. At the moment I am doing that for the energy equation following the book Viscous Fluid Flow by Frank M. White (3rd edition).

For incompressible flows with constant properties and no heat source the energy equation reads:

$\rho c_p\dfrac{\mathrm{D}T}{\mathrm{D}t}=k\nabla^2T+\Phi$,

where $\Phi$ is the dissipation function (given for a newtonian fluid):

$\Phi=\mu\left[2\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]$.

The term with $\lambda$ is not included in $\Phi$ because of the incompressible flow hypothesis.

Applying the Reynolds decomposition ($a=\overline{a}+a^{\prime}$ ) and averaging the energy equation, the result should be:

$\rho c_p\dfrac{\mathrm{D}\overline{T}}{\mathrm{D}t}=-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(q_i\right)+\overline{\Phi}$,

where

$q_i=-k\dfrac{\partial \overline{T}}{\partial x_i}+\rho c_p\overline{u_i^{\prime}T^{\prime}}$,

and

$\overline{\Phi}=\dfrac{\mu}{2}\overline{\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial u_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i} + \dfrac{\partial u_j^{\prime}}{\partial x_i}\right)^2}$.

My question is: how should the Einstein summation convention be expanded in the last expression? I want to double check my derivation and I am not sure about how to deal with that.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify what I am looking for, I would like to understand how to expand the following expression in Einstein summation convention form:

$\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial u_i^{\prime}}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i} + \dfrac{\partial u_j^{\prime}}{\partial x_i}$

Answer (score 1):

Using ISBN 978-2-85428-483-6, it is more obvious to use the symmetrical tensor: $s_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( \frac{\partial u_i}{x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{x_i})$ and $S_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( \frac{\partial U_i}{x_j} + \frac{\partial U_j}{x_i})$ and $\overline{S}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( \frac{\partial \overline{U}_i}{x_j} + \frac{\partial \overline{U}_j}{x_i})$, we have $\overline{\Phi} = \overline{\phi + \varphi}$ with $\phi = 2 \mu \overline{S}_{ij} \overline{S}_{ij}$ and $\varphi = 2\mu_{ij} \mu_{ij}$ so using your second expression: $\varphi=\mu\left[2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial x}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial y}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]$. The same applies for $\phi = \mu\left[2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{U}}{\partial x}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{V}}{\partial y}\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{W}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{U}}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{V}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{U}}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{W}}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{V}}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{W}}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]$

Comment: +1 Better use the same notation as in the question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the notation you used. I tried to look up the book you mentioned but unfortunately I could not find any resource available. Why you distinguish between $u$ and $U$? I have edited my question to clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{u}}{\partial z} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{v}}{\partial z} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial z}$ Notice how components are summed twice. Same applies for $u'$.

Comment: Thanks for showing the expansion of $\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}$. However what about $\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i}$? Does it expand in the same way? If so, is it true that $\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}+\dfrac{\partial u^{\prime}_i}{\partial x_j}+\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_j}}{\partial x_i}+\dfrac{\partial u^{\prime}_j}{\partial x_i}=2\left(\dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_j}+\dfrac{\partial u^{\prime}_i}{\partial x_j}\right)$?

Comment: No, it is a tensorial operation. What you have to square it the Tensor S described previously.  So $\Phi = \sum_i \sum_j \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \dots)$

Comment: I forgot a square sign at the end. I ll write the expression expanded in like 7 hours.

Comment: @PackSciences following your comment, I obtain the following: $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}=2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+2\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}+2\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$.

Comment: However, if $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$, then the result of my previous comment reads $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}=2\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$. If this is wrong, then I am missing something about how to carry out that tensorial operation.

Comment: $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}=2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+2\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}+2\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$ looks correct.

Comment: "However, if ∂ui∂xj=∂u∂x+∂u∂y+∂u∂z+∂v∂x+∂v∂y+∂v∂z+∂w∂x+∂w∂y+∂w∂z, then the result of my previous comment reads ∂ui∂xj+∂uj∂xi=2∂ui∂xj." No, that's not the case.